# Slow Select over View

Tags: postgresql, view, performance, join, postgresql-performance

My simple `SELECT` statement on a view in Postgres 9.3.1 is pretty slow. The receipts table has 20 million entries and the other one has around 17k.

But I still think it should be faster than ~16 seconds?

Table `receipts`:

```
     Column      |            Type           | Modifiers | Storage     | Stats target  | Description
-----------------+---------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------
 profitcenter    | character varying(5)      | not null  | extended    |               |
 receiptnumber   | bigint                    | not null  | plain       |               |
 receiptposition | character varying(6)      | not null  | extended    |               |
 date            | date                      | not null  | plain       |               |
 customerid      | integer                   |           | plain       |               |
 vkorg           | character varying(4)      |           | extended    |               |
 artikelnummer   | integer                   |           | plain       |               |
 price           | numeric(18,2)             |           | main        |               |
Indexes receiptnumber, date and customerid as B-Tree.
```

Table `cc_add_entry2`:

```
    Column     |          Type          | Modifiers | Storage     | Stats target  | Description
---------------+------------------------+-----------+-------------+---------------+--------------
 receiptnumber | bigint                 | not null  | plain       |               |
 customerid    | bigint                 |           | plain       |               |
 user          | character varying(255) |           | extended    |               |
 note          | text                   |           | extended    |               |
 date          | date                   |           | plain       |               |
Indexes receiptnumber, customerid as B-Tree.
```

The view is simple:

```
 SELECT s.receiptnumber,
    s.receiptposition,
    s.date,
    COALESCE(b.customerid, (s.customerid)::bigint) AS customerid,
    s.price
   FROM (dashboard.receipts s
     LEFT JOIN dashboard.cc_add_entry2 b ON ((s.receiptnumber = b.receiptnumber)));
```

`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` over a simple query:

```
explain analyze select * from test2 where customerid = 520001215;

 Hash Left Join  (cost=582.40..1086787.72 rows=100185 width=37) (actual time=2124.048..15937.744 rows=52 loops=1)
   Hash Cond: (s.receiptnumber = b.receiptnumber)
   Filter: (COALESCE(b.customerid, (s.customerid)::bigint) = 520001215)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 20036943
   ->  Seq Scan on receipts s  (cost=0.00..599969.96 rows=20036996 width=29) (actual time=0.904..7187.563 rows=20036995 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=360.51..360.51 rows=17751 width=16) (actual time=5.850..5.850 rows=17751 loops=1)
         Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 694kB
         ->  Seq Scan on cc_add_entry2 b  (cost=0.00..360.51 rows=17751 width=16) (actual time=0.005..2.537 rows=17751 l
oops=1)
 Total runtime: 15937.962 ms
```

Comment: The version on the server is 9.3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure the reason is that `customerid` in the view is the result of:

```
COALESCE(b.customerid, s.customerid::bigint)
```

After `LEFT JOIN`, cast & `COALESCE`, the predicate cannot be pushed down, so both tables have to be read in full, before the filter `customerid = 520001215` can be applied. The fact that `customerid` can be NULL in both tables is not helping either. Can at least one be set to `NOT NULL`?

Extremely inefficient.

Run this query, and compare performance:

```
SELECT r.receiptnumber
    ,  r.receiptposition
    ,  r.date
    ,  c.customerid
    ,  r.price
FROM   dashboard.cc_add_entry2 c 
JOIN   dashboard.receipts r USING (receiptnumber)
WHERE  c.customerid = 520001215;

UNION ALL
SELECT r.receiptnumber
    ,  r.receiptposition
    ,  r.date
    ,  r.customerid::bigint
    ,  r.price
FROM   dashboard.receipts r
LEFT   JOIN dashboard.cc_add_entry2 c USING (receiptnumber)
WHERE  r.customerid = 520001215
AND    c.customerid IS NULL;
```

Should be much faster. If you can't wrap it into a view, either use this query instead or write a SQL or plpgsql function that takes `customerid` as parameter.

Also these multicolumn indices would help some more:

```
CREATE INDEX foo1 ON dashboard.cc_add_entry2 (customerid, receiptnumber);
CREATE INDEX foo2 ON dashboard.cc_add_entry2 (receiptnumber)
WHERE customerid IS NULL;
CREATE INDEX foo3 ON dashboard.receipts (customerid, receiptnumber);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I did manage to make a plpgsql function with your query. I do not know how to make this into a view with the same performance.

Comment: @Beig: What's the performance now? Several orders of magnitude faster, right?

Comment: Yep, the query takes ~7ms.

Answer (score -3):

Do you have clustered and nonclustered indexes? Try clustered index on receipt number and date. And non clustered index on receipt number, receipt position, date, and price

Comment: Postgres does not have clustered indexes.